# Open .csv file, change column format and save in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I can't crack this one...can anyone help?  I have a number of files emailed to me each day and I have a routine to save these on a network share.  The original Excel csv files have the date fields in columns A & B as 'DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00', I need this to be 'DD/MM/YY'.  I can do this by opening each file, selecting the columns, changing the column format and saving but I can't get this to automate in VBA.  The current iteration of my code (I've been around the block many times with this) is below.  When I run this code it saves the file in the new location but the reformatting of columns doesn't work, the columns remain in the original format :-(

```
Function F_PREPARE_GENESYS_FILES()
'Finds current day Genesys files on K: drive, copies them to another folder and changes     format before data import process

On Error GoTo F_PREPARE_GENESYS_FILES_Err

Dim db As Database
Dim App As New Excel.Application
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim MyFile2 As String
Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileName As Variant

Set db = CurrentDb

FromPath = "\\chs114file1\dovpasres$\Statistics\Totem\Genesys_reports\"
ToPath = "\\chs114file1\dovpasres$\Statistics\Totem\RunTime\"
FileName = Format([Forms]![Processing]![ProcessDate], "yyyy-mm-dd_") & "*"

FSO.CopyFile FromPath & FileName, ToPath

MyFile = Dir(ToPath)
'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
Do While MyFile <> ""

Set wbk = App.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=ToPath & MyFile)
    
    MyFile2 = Left(MyFile, Len(MyFile) - 4)

        Sheets(MyFile2).Select
        Range("A:B").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True, FileName:=MyFile
    'wbk.SaveAs MyFile, xlCSVUTF8
MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder
Loop
```

Comment: Try `Range("A:B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"`

Comment: If only it were that simple...I'm afraid that didn't work either.  Thank you though.

Comment: `Range("A:B").NumberFormatLocal = "dd/mm/yyyy"` ??

Comment: No, still no good I'm afraid.  Gives me more reading-up to do though...thanks again.

Comment: Just asking, but, are you saving as .csv, or are you saving as .xlsx?

Comment: As .csv maintaining same file format but changing format of cells in first two columns only.

Comment: Excel formatting does not save to a .csv file.

Comment: CSV files are content-only: they contain no formatting information.  If I format half a column of dates as mm/dd/yyyy and the other half as mm/dd/yy and save to CSV, the *text* in the CSV (opened in eg. Notepad) reflects that, but if I open that file in Excel all the dates will have the same default date format.

Comment: Thanks bugdrown & Tim...this was a concern of mine but I'm able to do it 'manually' (as described above), just not automating through vba!?  Will be AFK for a while now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edited

I suspect it's a mistake to think of "Excel csv files" because CSV files are nothing but plain text. When Excel opens them, it reads the contents as text. Those dates that appear as 'DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00' are just text. Excel cannot reformat them unless it sees them as dates, so variations of `Range("A:B").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` won't help.

One way to handle this is to add a formula in a temp column that converts the text to actual dates and format that column as desired. Then you can `Copy - PasteSpecial` it where you need it. The simple example below creates the formula in Column B, does the `PasteSpecial` to overwrite the input text dates in Column A, then deletes the temp formula. In your case, the `Set rngFormula` statement should offset to the right as far as needed. The `.FormulaR1C1` statement should refer back that number of columns. For example, if your formula is in column E, the `c[-1]` in `"=DATEVALUE(r[0]c[-1])` should be `c[-4]`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DateConvert()
    Dim rngInput As Range, rngFormula As Range
    
    Set rngInput = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Resize(5, 1) ' Input in Column A
    Set rngFormula = rngInput.Offset(0, 1) ' Temp formula in Column B
    
    With rngFormula
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(r[0]c[-1])" ' Same row, 1 column to left
        .NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
        .Copy
        rngInput.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        .Clear  ' Delete the temp formula
    End With
    
End Sub
```

This shows the output in a separate column (sorry, my input text dates are mm/dd/yyyy, but the output is correct):

|  | **A** | **B** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | Text Input 'DD/MM/YYYY 00:00:00' | Excel Date (Output) |
| **2** | 1/31/2023 12:34:56 | 31/1/2023 |
| **3** | 2/28/2023 12:34:56 | 28/2/2023 |
| **4** | 3/31/2023 12:34:56 | 31/3/2023 |
| **5** | 4/30/2023 12:34:56 | 30/4/2023 |
| **6** | 12/31/2023 12:34:56 | 31/12/2023 |

Comment: Thank you so much Richard…that makes perfect sense.  I’ll try this when I’m back at work on Monday.

Comment: Hi Richard...this worked a treat!  Very many thanks :-)

Comment: Hi All.  I seem to have encountered a problem since the turn of the month, I'm assuming because the text input is showing only a single digit for the day/month?  30/6/23 was okay but 1/7/23 is not.  Any ideas how I can adapt the code above so that the 'DATEVALUE' considers a leading zero in the output?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a guess, but do you have to tweak your locale settings? That's all I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for getting back to me!  I’ll look into that tomorrow morning…I’m fairly convinced that my locale settings are set for UK and the short date format but it’s worth a try.  Many thanks.

Comment: Hi Richard.  No change I'm afraid :-(  I've even added this to the 'open workbook' line of code:

Set wbk = App.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=ToPath & MyFile, local:= True)

It's showing the cell content as '#VALUE' and pasting that into columns A & B...I don't get it, ant further thoughts?  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: According to MS, "DateValue recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to the Short Date format that you specified for your system" so I have to assume that's one thing to check. Also check the time entries. The same MS doc says "...if date includes invalid time information (such as "89:98"), an error occurs". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datevalue-function

Comment: Many thanks Richard.  I’ll certainly read-up on that.  Many thanks once again.